# How to customize react-show-more more or less text to Material-UI Icons

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react show more text controller in my spfx webpart using react. i need to replace showMore and showLess string link with ExpandMore and ExpandLess material ui icons in my webpart.is there any method for this?

```html
<ShowMoreText
  /* Default options */
  lines={2}
  more="Show More"
  less="Show less"
  anchorClass=""
  onClick={this.executeOnClick}
  expanded={false}
>
  {item["description"]}
</ShowMoreText>
```

I refered this https://npmjs.com/package/react-show-more-text

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-show-more-text i referred this

Comment: <ShowMoreText
                /* Default options */
                lines={2}
                more='Show More'                
                less='Show less'
                anchorClass=''
                onClick={this.executeOnClick}
                expanded={false}                
            >
                {item["description"]}
            </ShowMoreText> i need the following material icons in show and less string props

Comment: is there any method to add icon in     more='Show More'                
            less='Show less'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method

Pass the `<Icon />` directly to related props would work fine.

```
<ShowMoreText
  more={<ExpandMore />}
  less={<ExpandLess />}
  ...
/>
```

#### Demo

[image]

---

#### Source

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import ShowMoreText from "react-show-more-text";
import ExpandLess from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandLess";
import ExpandMore from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

export default function App() {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  const onClick = () => {
    setExpand(!expand);
  };
  const text = "12313131313131311";
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ShowMoreText
        lines={2}
        more={<ExpandMore />}
        less={<ExpandLess />}
        onClick={onClick}
        expanded={expand}
        width={30}
      >
        {text}
      </ShowMoreText>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit kind-tesla-pd525]

Comment: it shows [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
***Failed to load component "4a4b6a0e-941e-4cb8-99ed-42b480f42980" (VerticalTimelineWpWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component "4a4b6a0e-941e-4cb8-99ed-42b480f42980" (VerticalTimelineWpWebPart). Original error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Comment: @BiniJacob It's not related to this post, kindly check the online demo would be appreciated.